# Is there a problem in perl 5.12.2 using splice on @ISA?

Tags: perl, oop, universal

The following is a debug session on Perl 5.12. Does this make any sense? Does `UNIVERSAL` cache a version of the `@ISA` variable, which if forever uses thereafer. Back before [`Class::ISA`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aISA) was deprecated, I used to call `Class::ISA::self_and_super_path` to get the internals to relook at the `@ISA` array. Since it is now considered unnecessary, how do you get perl to audit its internal records?

```
DB<34> p $papa
Papushka=HASH(0x16bc0300)

DB<35> p $papa->isa('Nanushka')

DB<36> p $papa->isa('Babushka')
1

DB<37> x @Papushka::ISA
0  'Nanushka'
1  'Babushka'
```

This is test code (obviously). It's getting the same results, run flat, run as a test, or run in debug. I should tell you that prior to this `@ISA = qw<Babushka>` and I performed

```
splice( @ISA, 0, 0, 'Nanushka' );
```

Is that the problem? Should you only ever `push` onto `@ISA`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The replacement for `Class::ISA::self_and_super_path` is `mro::get_linear_isa`. That's available either from `mro` itself, or, if you want to support old perls, via `MRO::Compat`.

Also, `@ISA` is a magic variable.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump \@ISA'
SV = IV(0x1b92e20) at 0x1b92e28
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x1bbcd58
  SV = PVAV(0x1b93cf8) at 0x1bbcd58
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (SMG,RMG)
    MAGIC = 0x1bc0f68
      MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_isa
      MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_isa(I)
      MG_OBJ = 0x1bbcd40
    ARRAY = 0x0
    FILL = -1
    MAX = -1
    ARYLEN = 0x0
    FLAGS = (REAL)
```

Note the `PERL_MAGIC_isa`. That's what drives this particular mechanism.

Whenever it is changed, the contents of any caches that rely on its value are supposed to be updated.

```
$ perl -E'say Foo->isa(q[Bar]) || 0; @Foo::ISA = qw(Bar Baz); say Foo->isa(q[Bar]) || 0'
0
1
```

Apparently you've found a case where the cache invalidation doesn't happen. I consider this a bug. Chances are `splice`, for some reason, doesn't invoke the `isa` magic appropriately. You could try to modify `@ISA` in an alternative way, for example using `unshift` or an assignment, or possibly try `mro::method_changed_in`, which would invalidate the method resolution caches, which are bound to the various `@ISA`s.

If you could reduce this bug to a minimal testcase, that'd be hugely helpful in getting this bug fixed.

**Update:**

A minimal testcase turned out to be easy:

```
$ perl -E'say Foo->isa(q[Bar]) || 0; splice @Foo::ISA, 0, 0, q[Bar]; say Foo->isa(q[Bar]) || 0'
0
0
```

This is caused by `pp_splice` not doing something like `mg_set((SV *)ary)`. `push`, `unshift`, and regular assignments do that correctly, so using one of these should fix your issue.

**Another Update:**

[This change](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commitdiff/474af99058f4c0fc3b80d73763da5b29c1ff8c66), which I just committed to perl, fixes the issue. However, as the odd behaviour of `splice` not invoking magic is already present in 5.8 and 5.10, it's not a regression and therefore not going to be part of 5.12.3 in a few months. 5.13.6, which will be released next week, and 5.14.0, next northern spring, will probably have it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a cache. But if you can modify `@ISA` without invalidating that cache, I would consider it a bug in perl.

Does your problem disappear if you add the line `@ISA = @ISA;` after your `splice` line?

Comment: Definitely will try `@ISA=@ISA`. Except it will be more like `@$isa_ref = @$isa_ref`. Where `$isa_ref = *Papushka::ISA{ARRAY}`.